Geodesic variation and the (Riemann) curvature tensor -- what about uniform gravitational fields?
BACKGROUND: The equation of geodesic variation is in almost every GR book. Suppose $x(s)$ and $x(s)+\epsilon(s)$ are two nearby geodesics at $x$, with $\epsilon(s)$ small, and also $d\epsilon(s)/ds$ small (meaning that $\epsilon(s)$ remains small during the interval from $s$ to $s+ds$). If $D/D\lambda$ is the covariant derivative along a curve, then
$$\frac{D^2\epsilon^\mu}{Ds^2}=R^\mu_{\kappa\tau\rho}\frac{dx^\kappa}{ds}\frac{dx^\tau}{ds}\epsilon^\rho.$$
To more easily interpret this, suppose two particles are freely falling along nearby geodesics, assuming $ϵ^μ$ and $dϵ^μ/ds$ are small. If the particles’ time coordinates $x^0$ are synchronized at $x$, then both particles have approximately the same geodesic coordinate systems. Then the equation becomes
$$\frac{d^2\epsilon^\mu}{ds^2}=R^\mu_{\kappa\tau\rho}\frac{dx^\kappa}{ds}\frac{dx^\tau}{ds}\epsilon^\rho.$$
(The covariant derivative and the ordinary derivative along the curve are the same in geodesic coordinates, since the Christoffel symbols vanish.) Thus, there appears to be a tidal force, determined by the curvature tensor, which causes the geodesics to deviate.
QUESTION: Consider an infinitely long "wire" with mass density $\sigma$ per unit length. By symmetry, the geodesic path of a particle starting from rest is a straight line perpendicular to the wire. (Alternatively, consider an infinite plane with mass density $\sigma$ per unit length squared. The geodesic path of a particle starting from rest is a straight line perpendicular to the plane.) In this case, there is no geodesic variation. Two particles which start $\epsilon^\rho$ apart always remain $\epsilon^\rho$ apart.
This seems to imply that all the components of the curvature tensor $R^\mu_{\kappa\tau\rho}$ vanish, which would imply flat spacetime. Yet, there is a gravitational field, so spacetime cannot be flat.
What's going on here?

Could you elaborate on the sentence "By symmetry, all geodesics are straight lines perpendicular to the wire." Won't the geodesic depend on its initial conditions or am I misunderstanding your intention here?

Sorry, I should have said two particles starting from rest, a distance $\epsilon$ apart, will experience no deviation.

I am not sure about the correctness of my answer, so please be lenient. However, I suppose the crucial part here is to realise that this is just one special case of initial data where the geodesic deviation vanishes as opposed to other initial data where it does not. This is analogous to e.g. a metric $g$ not being zero $g \equiv 0$ just because
$$g(X,Y) = 0$$
for some vectors $X,Y$. One may find cases in your example above, where the geodesic deviation does not vanish. Let the initial coordinates of particle 1 be $(r_1, \varphi_1, z_1)$ and the initial coordinates of particle 2 be $(r_2, \varphi_2, z_2)$ in usual cylindrical coordinates (which are of course appropriate coordinates for the wire setting). Then e.g. the cases

$r_1 = r_2, \; \; \varphi_1 \neq \varphi_2, \; \; z_1 = z_2$

$r_1 \neq r_2, \; \; \varphi_1 = \varphi_2, \; \; z_1 = z_2$

...


will not lead to $\tfrac{D^2 \epsilon^{\mu}}{Ds^2} = 0$. To be honest, I did not verify that last claim mathematically, however it seems to me intuitively clear; I will gladly try to verify it if you want me to.
The term $R^{\mu}_{\nu \rho \lambda} \dot{x}^{\nu} \dot{x}^{\rho} \epsilon^{\lambda}$ with the initial data you considered $r_1 = r_2, \; \; \varphi_1 = \varphi_2, \; \; z_1 \neq z_2$ possibly just happens to sum up to zero.

Excellent! Your two examples are very clear. I was extrapolating a special case and making an unwarranted conclusion. Thank you.
